# How to set a different Id with @FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml

It is very nice to use the `@FXML` annotation so the `FXMLLoader` can inject the fields with an instance of the control with the same id as the field name.

But it would be nice, if I can set a different id than the field name.
For example in the FXML there is a `TextArea` with the id *user* and in the controller class there would a field *txtUser*. I would expect something like

```
    @FXML(id = "user")
    private TextArea txtUser;
```

Naming the controls in the FXML like *txtUser* is not nice.
Becouse a controller manage typically a reference to the data model too, say this is a user

```
    // The data model
    private User user;
```

, there would be naming conflicts: Should the ui control or the data model get the field name *user*?

Comment: Have you tried `private TextArea txtUser; txtUser.setId("user");` ?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun thanks for your suggestion! Did you mean, that the id should altered after the FXML file is loaded? If so, thats not real solution, becouse the problem is the naming at design time not at runtime.